# Formula Interpretation

Tags: calculus, functions

Good Afternoon to everyone!

I am having some troubles understanding the meaning of formula (4) which I found in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00034-015-0136-z).

The formula is the following:

$$k = \min \{k:2^k.N_c\geq A_c\} $$

A little bit of context:

- $k$ is a scalar value
- $N_c$ and $A_c$ are vectors of scalar values

I know it should compute $k$ based on the minimum between two terms, but I still find hard to understand both the colon and the low dot in between the $2^k$ and the $N_c$.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: I expect that the colon means "such that" and that the low dot means multiplication.  I don't know what it might mean to say that one vector is greater than another, though.  Perhaps the paper makes that clear.

Comment: @lulu Sometimes, especially in convex optimization problems, $u \ge 0$ where $u$ is a vector means that all elements of $u$ are nonnegative.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Sure, and perhaps that's what's intended here.  But I wouldn't call that obvious.

Comment: I have also seen the notation $\ a\ge b\ $ used to indicate that each entry of the (row or column) vector $\ a\ $ is no smaller than the corresponding entry of $\ b\ $.  I can't see any other obvious interpretation.

Comment: @lulu Agree with that!

Comment: @lonzaleggiera  Lexicographic order is also quite common.  $\vec v>\vec w$ if, in the first unequal component, $\vec v$ has the larger entry. (obviously, assuming a coordinate basis has been specified). And of course there may be an order (or partial order) specific to the problem at hand.

Comment: First of all thanks to all! To answer @lulu the paper does not make that super clear unfortunately, but yes Nc and Ac are slotted vector because k is computed for independent values, so for each unique value there is a value of Nc and a value of Ac.

Comment: Well, as I say, I don't think we can guess what order (or partial order) the authors might be considering.  In the comments, people have discussed two options (one partial, one total).  Maybe one of those is correct, maybe not.  the paper is behind a paywall so I doubt anyone here will check it.  But I expect it is defined somewhere there.